# AutoCOmplete not giving autocomplete undefined error in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to add AutoComplete in my html

[JQUERY AUTOCOMPLETE FILE LINK](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Javascript_Free_Code/UI/Download_jquery_ui_extensions_Free_Java_Code.htm)
Here is how i have added it

```
<script src="<?php echo $site_root?>js/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.autoSelect.js"></script>
```

Trying to access using

```
$("#username").autocomplete({
        source: <?php echo $username; ?>,   
        select: function(event, ui) 
        {
            var username = ui.item.label;
            window.location = 'submissionForm.php?username=' + username;
        }
    });
```

I am getting This error
Cannot read property 'autocomplete' of undefined

What is wrong?

Comment: you need to use jquery-ui.min.js.
Try to download this and include in your script file

Comment: You don't need the complete `minified` version, that will solve it yes. But that's not what he needs. He needs the core and perhaps some other files for jquery UI to work. Open autocomplete file, read the comment on top.

Comment: i have tried adding min version it does fix this error but the error moved to second line of the fiel saying undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the autocomplete file you'll see something like:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "./core",
    "./widget",
    "./position",
    "./menu"
], factory );
```

Those are the files you need additionally, in that order, on the page.

```
<script src="path-to/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path-to/jquery-ui/ui/core.js"></script>
<script src="path-to/jquery-ui/ui/widget.js"></script>
<script src="path-to/jquery-ui/ui/position.js"></script>
<script src="path-to/jquery-ui/ui/menu.js"></script>
<script src="path-to/jquery-ui/ui/autocomplete.js"></script>
```

If you don't care for any future additions regarding widgets, go get the complete minified version of jquery UI.

Also CSS is important! To use custom builds, you propably don't want any aditional widget CSS since that will never be used.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you've added the necessary dependencies (jquery and jquery-ui)

Then wrap your call like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#username").autocomplete({
    ...
    });
})
```

I'd suggest having a look at the demo page included in the .rar